# difficulty splitting, searching and printing document in python 3

Tags: python, list, dictionary, set, document

Hey guys this is pretty rudimentary stuff but I'm struggling to manipulate a simple text doc for an assignment. Within the text there are multiple stories separated by "NEW DOCUMENT". I'm supposed to put them in a dictionary and be able to retrieve them based on index number or by search terms. So far my dictionary contains all the words in the text as keys and their location in each doc as the value. If one word appears in multiple docs it has multiple values. I can't think of a way to search for a string in the dictionary though and return the indexes of all the documents that contain that exact phrase.

```
def main_menu():
file = open("ap_docs2.txt", 'r')
dict1 = {}
docNum = 0
numList = []
for line in file:
    line = line.strip("\n")
    line = line.strip('.')
    line = line.strip(',')
    line = line.lower()
    if line == "<new document>":
        docNum += 1
    else:
        line = line.split()
        for i in line:
            if i in dict1:
                dict1[i].add(docNum)
            else:
                 dict1[i] = set(numList)
                 dict1[i].add(docNum)
```

this is my search function:

```
def search(dict1):
user_input = input("Enter the phrases you'd like to search")
user_input = user_input.lower()
user_input = user_input.strip("\n")
user_input = user_input.strip('.')
user_input = user_input.strip(',')
list1 = user_input.split()
print(list1)
for i in list1:
    if i in dict1:
        print(i, "is found in", dict1[i], "documents")
```

this is the document:

```
<NEW DOCUMENT>
Look on the bright 
side of Life.
<NEW DOCUMENT>
look on the very, dark
side of the Moon
<NEW DOCUMENT>
is there life
on the moon
```

if I search for "the moon" for example it returns:

```
the is found in documents {1, 2, 3}
moon is found in documents {2, 3}
```

I want to be able to search for the whole phrase rather than a term. And then return any documents that have that whole phrase. I appreciate the help and I'm sorry it's probably a really easy fix I've just been stuck for a while.

Answer (score 0):

I would create the dictionary with the full story texts as the keys and the document numbers as the values. Then just check if the user inputed phrase is in one of the keys and then get the document number like this:

```
for key in story_document_dict:
  if phrase in key:
    return story_document_dict[key]
```

Comment: first line can be `for key in dict:` (dict is a bad name though)